# Work with Object.defineProperty and its 'get' function

Tags: javascript, oop, object, properties

I read a few books about JavaScript, and it is a very powerful language for building web applications using OOP, but now I have a problem that I don't know if it can be solved:

```
var myObj = {};
myObj.properties = {};
myObj.properties.myProperty = 'foo';
```

Let me explain, now I have `myObj` .. setted the `properties` object inside... now, if I ask 
for `myObj.properties.myProperty` I will get `foo`. But what if I ask for `myObj.properties.notSettedValue` ? (that is `undefined`)

I read about `Object.defineProperty` on MDN that can set a setter and a getter on a property.

I tried to set the `"get"` value on `myObj.properties`

```
Object.defineProperty(myObj, 'properties', { 
    get : function(){ 
        console.log("called custom get property.", this, arguments); 
    } 
});
```

... but nothing to do, the `get` function declared for `myObj.properties` work only for itself. The custom function is called only when I request `myObj.properties`. Not for its children.

There's a solution to pass the requested `myObj.properties.notSettedValue` to a `get` function of `myObj.properties`?

(without using a function or a method like `myObj.properties.getItem('notSettedValue')`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you're asking is whether it's possible to set up a function that gets called if code tries to retrieve a property from an object that doesn't exist on that object.

No, JavaScript doesn't have that ability. ES6's [proxies](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony%3adirect_proxies) will make something quite similar possible, but as of ES5, there is no "catch all" getter feature.

Your only ES5-compatible mechanism for doing that kind of catch-all is as you've said, using a function rather than a property (your `getItem`).

Comment: I suspected it.... although there are some "magic" feature in JavaScript, not all is possible right now.. more than a decade is passed from ES3 to ES5 ... how many times we will wait for ES6? ...

Comment: @Salcos: Not nearly so long, I'm glad to say. The relevant people got their act together. You can look at the latest [draft specifications for ES6 here](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:specification_drafts). I don't think it'll be finalized in 2014, but I suspect it will in 2015, so that's about six years since 5.0 and four years since 5.1. But ES6 is *big changes* compared to ES5.

Answer (score 0):

Object in JavaScript are dynamic. You can add new properties on the fly, like you did in you example e.g. `myObj.properties = {}`

What happens under the hood is that the interpreter will try to find a property called `properties` on the `myObj` instance; If there is no such property then it will navigate through the prototype chain. In this example it will visit the prototype of the Object constructor, as `myObj` is an object literal. If it cannot find that property in the prototype chain then it will create it and add it as a new member of the object.

The same applies when you want to read a property. But in this case it will return undefined if it can't find the requested property; So unless you explicitly define the property, it will always return undefined. This applies both for when you access a simple property and a ES5 property.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It just describes how properties work, which the OP seems to already (mostly) understand.

Comment: Well it seems to me that he doesn't understand

Comment: The question rambles a bit, but it's fairly clear: Is there a way to get a function called when code accesses a property that doesn't exist?

Comment: Yes and i answered the question by saying no. With the current version of EcmaScript it is not possible.